# How to fix graph so it doesn't write over itself when resizing

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am trying to make my graph resize with the window when changed. I put my code that makes the graph in a function and added an event listener that calls the main function with updated height and width variables when added however it doesn't remove the already added in bars, lines, axes, labels, etc. causing an effect where the graph rescales properly but doesn't remove all the old stuff so I end up with hundreds of bars on my graph.

I tried just putting in a white rectangle each time the window resizes, however it takes too long for the graph to load in such a way that it flickers while resizing and doesn't look good.
Also to note: I have the function `chart()` run on load in my HTML file. Here is a link to what it looks like:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/SSRtp.jpg

```
var margin = {top: 10, right: 70, bottom: 100, left: 70},
    w = window.innerWidth, 
    h = window.innerHeight;
var topBottom = margin.top + margin.bottom;
var leftRight = margin.left + margin.right;  
var mid = {x: w/2, y:h/2};
var svg = d3.select("#svgDiv")
  .append("svg")
  .attr("width",w)
  .attr("height",h)
  .attr("margin","auto");
function chart(){
    w = window.innerWidth; 
    h = window.innerHeight;
    d3.csv("test.csv").then(function(dataset) {
        part where I make the graph
    }
}
window.addEventListener("resize",chart);
```

Should I just remove everything and redraw it whenever 'chart()' is called? or should I better optimize my code and then just put a white rectangle over old window sizes so that the one that is desired is on top.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're going to use resize events, you can do two things. Either remove all children of `svg` before drawing (`svg.selectAll("*").remove();`) anything, or, if you want to optimize the code, split the loading and handling of the data and the drawing of the chart into two parts.

First, when you load the data, store it as a variable and use the `.data` attribute to add/remove SVG nodes based on it. For example, if you have three bars in the data, you add the `rect` nodes here, but don't do anything about their placement.

Then, inside the function that is also called on resize, you first take the `xScale` and `yScale` variables and call `.range()` with the new size. Take the variable you assigned the three `rect` nodes to, and set their `x`, `y`, `width`, and `height` attributes based on their values as you loaded them in the first part. Note that all these values are indirectly based on the values you passed to `xScale` and `yScale` `.range()` function.

I can't help you more specifically without seeing more code, so I hope this helps.